What is a good way to perform a SHA256d hash (double SHA256) on an OpenBSD fresh install?
What is a good way to perform a SHA256d hash (double SHA256) on the default terminal of an network isolated OpenBSD fresh install?
Here's what I'm doing:
echo test > testfile
cat testfile | openssl dgst -binary | openssl dgst

It gives me a number ending in 0xe0b6
Just wondering if there is a more concise/otherwise better way?

if this is what you want to execute, it seems to be the right thing; what is bad about it, if we are to improve it?

(I mean, aside from the useless use of cat, but I'm not sure using <testfile openssl dgst -binary | openssl dgst is that much better than cat testfile | ….

@MarcusMüller perhaps it is the right thing. I was wondering if there is a sha256d native function or something similar I'm missing though.

I would have many questions on why someone would want such a function! I believe there's no such function, no. That sounds something cryptographically highly dubious, not something you'd want to see in your cryptographic suites :)

It would be hard to improve on the script at https://calomel.org/ids_mtree.html.

openssl dgst -binary testfile | sha256

... is shorter, but there is no built-in way of applying the SHA256 hash twice on some input in any of the base utilities on OpenBSD.
